# Why am I getting worst performance with a private dynamic array

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, performance, openmp

I want to use OpenMP to parallelize a for-loop calculator which does something like:

```
B = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * N); //N is known
for(i=0;i<500000;i++)
{  
    for(j=0;j<M;j++) B[j]=i+j;  //M is different from N, but M <= N;
    some operations on B which produce a variable L;
    printf("%d\n",L);    
}
```

I don't need to re-allocate B as its values will be defined for each iteration accordingly. The operations will only use B[0] to B[M-1]. This saves a lot of time in allocating and initialization of B.

In order to use openmp, I changed the code to this:

```
#pragma omp parallel num_threads(32) private(i,j,B,M,L)
{
  B = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * N); //N is known
  #pragma omp parallel for 
  for(i=0;i<500000;i++)
  {  
      for(j=0;j<M;j++) B[j]=i+j;  //M is different from N, but M <= N;
      some operations on B which produce a variable L;
      printf("%d\n",L);    
  }
}
```

It runs really slow compared to the first one, as it creates a new B array for each thread (so 500000 times).
Is there a way to avoid this using openmp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue is that the iterations of the loop are not being assigned to threads as you wanted. Because you have added again the clause `parallel` to `#pragma omp for`, and assuming that you have nested parallelism disabled, which by default it is, each of the threads created in the outer `parallel` region will execute "sequentially" the code within that region, namely:

```
  #pragma omp parallel for 
  for(i=0;i<500000;i++){  
      ...
  }
```

Therefore, each thread will execute all the `500000` iterations of the inner loop that you intended to be parallelized. Consequently, removing the parallelism and adding additional overhead (*e.g.,* thread creation) to the sequential code. Nonetheless, one can easily solve this issue by merely removing the second `parallel` clause, namely:

```
#pragma omp parallel num_threads(32) private(i,j,B,M,L)
{
    B = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * N); //N is known
    #pragma omp for 
    for(i=0;i<500000;i++){  
      ...   
    }
}
```

Depending upon the setup where the code will be executed (*e.g.,* in a `NUMA` architecture or not, if the `malloc` function used is (or not) thread-aware memory allocator, among others) it might be advisable to profile your parallel region to check if it pays off (or not) to move the allocation of the `2D` array to the outside of that region. An example, of what the alternative version might look like:

```
int total_threads = 32;
int** B = malloc(sizeof(*int) * total_threads);
for(int i = 0; i < total_threads; i++){
    B[i] = malloc(N * sizeof(int));
}

#pragma omp parallel num_threads(32) private(i,j,M,L)
{
  int threadID = omp_get_thread_num();
  #pragma omp for 
  for(i=0;i<500000;i++)
  {  
      for(j=0;j<M;j++) 
          B[threadID][j]=i+j;  //M is different from N, but M <= N;
      some operations on B which produce a variable L;
      printf("%d\n",L);    
  }
}
// you might need to reduce all the values from all threads
// to main thread array.
```